# Why do my field-based Jackson mixins break when using Lombok @Data?

Tags: java, jackson, lombok, jackson-databind

I have a project which uses both [Jackson](https://github.com/FasterXML/jackson) and [Lombok](https://github.com/rzwitserloot/lombok).  It is using the current latest versions of both (Jackson 2.12.2 & Lombok 1.18.18).  I have the following class containing a Jackson mapped object, with an associated [Jackson mixin](https://github.com/FasterXML/jackson-docs/wiki/JacksonMixInAnnotations), allowing it to be deserialized either ignoring the given field or not, depending on whether the mixin is passed to the `ObjectMapper`:

```java
import com.fasterxml.jackson.annotation.JsonProperty;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.core.JsonProcessingException;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.json.JsonMapper;

public class IssueDemonstration {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws JsonProcessingException {
        JsonMapper jsonMapper = JsonMapper.builder().build();
        JsonMapper mixinMapper = JsonMapper.builder()
                .addMixIn(Example.class, ExampleMixin.class).build();

        String json = "{\"value\": \"Some Value\"}";
        System.out.println(
                "Default: " + jsonMapper.readValue(json, Example.class).getValue());
        System.out.println(
                "Mixin: " + mixinMapper.readValue(json, Example.class).getValue());
    }

    private static class Example {
        @JsonProperty(access = JsonProperty.Access.READ_ONLY)
        private String value;

        public String getValue() {
            return value;
        }

        public void setValue(String value) {
            this.value = value;
        }
    }

    private abstract static class ExampleMixin {
        @JsonProperty(access = JsonProperty.Access.READ_WRITE)
        private String value;
    }
}
```

The above code gives the expected results:

```
Default: null
Mixin: Some Value
```

However, if I change `Example` to use Lombok's [`@Data`](https://projectlombok.org/features/Data) to automagically generate the getter & setter, the mixin no longer works:

```java
@Data
private static class Example {
    @JsonProperty(access = JsonProperty.Access.READ_ONLY)
    private String value;
}
```

Output:

```
Default: null
Mixin: null
```

Why is this not working when I switch to using `@Data`?  I see nothing in the Jackson [`@Data`](https://projectlombok.org/features/Data) or [`@Getter and @Setter`](https://projectlombok.org/features/GetterSetter) documentation that indicate that this should behave in this manner.

Answer (score 2):

The issue is that Lombok is copying the Jackson `@JsonProperty` annotation to the generated setter.  In Jackson, annotations on accessor methods take precedence over the same annotations on fields.  Therefore, the annotation on the `getValue()` method in the `Example` class is overriding the annotation on the `value` field in `ExampleMixin`.

This can be fixed in a number of ways.  The mixin can be changed to have a Jackson-annotated setter (thus triggering an override of the Lombok setter), either manually or by annotating the mixin field using `@Setter`:

```java
private interface ExampleMixin {
    @JsonProperty(access = JsonProperty.Access.READ_WRITE)
    void setValue(String value);
}
```

```java
private abstract static class ExampleMixin {
    @Setter
    @JsonProperty(access = JsonProperty.Access.READ_WRITE)
    private String value;
}
```

Alternatively, the deserialized class can be changed to have an unannotated manual setter created for it in addition to the annotated field, thus preventing Lombok from creating an annotated one:

```java
@Data
private static class Example {
    @JsonProperty(access = JsonProperty.Access.READ_ONLY)
    private String value;

    public void setValue(String value) {
        this.value = value;
    }
}
```

---

One tricky thing about this whole situation is the fact that the copying of Jackson annotations to the setter does not appear documented in Lombok.  The [documentation](https://projectlombok.org/features/GetterSetter) mentions nullability annotations as being copied over, but makes no mention of the copied Jackson annotations:

> `lombok.copyableAnnotations` = [A list of fully qualified types] (default: empty list)
> Lombok will copy any of these annotations from the field to the setter parameter, and to the getter method. Note that lombok ships with a bunch of annotations 'out of the box' which are known to be copyable: All popular nullable/nonnull annotations.

> Various well-known annotations about nullability, such as `org.eclipse.jdt.annotation.NonNull`, are automatically copied over to the right place (method for getters, parameter for setters). You can specify additional annotations that should always be copied via lombok configuration key `lombok.copyableAnnotations`.

A look at the [Lombok source code](https://github.com/rzwitserloot/lombok/blob/v1.18.18/src/core/lombok/core/handlers/HandlerUtil.java#L316-L329), however, reveals the copied Jackson annotations:

```java
COPY_TO_SETTER_ANNOTATIONS = Collections.unmodifiableList(Arrays.asList(new String[] {
    "com.fasterxml.jackson.annotation.JacksonInject",
    "com.fasterxml.jackson.annotation.JsonAlias",
    "com.fasterxml.jackson.annotation.JsonFormat",
    "com.fasterxml.jackson.annotation.JsonIgnore",
    "com.fasterxml.jackson.annotation.JsonIgnoreProperties",
    "com.fasterxml.jackson.annotation.JsonProperty",
    "com.fasterxml.jackson.annotation.JsonSetter",
    "com.fasterxml.jackson.annotation.JsonSubTypes",
    "com.fasterxml.jackson.annotation.JsonTypeInfo",
    "com.fasterxml.jackson.annotation.JsonView",
    "com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.annotation.JsonDeserialize",
    "com.fasterxml.jackson.dataformat.xml.annotation.JacksonXmlProperty",
}));
```

The mixin field issue, including the lack of documentation, is captured as issue [#2769](https://github.com/rzwitserloot/lombok/issues/2769) in the Lombok issue tracker.

Answer (score 0):

[Lombok @Data](https://projectlombok.org/api/lombok/Data.html) is equivalent to @Getter @Setter @RequiredArgsConstructor @ToString @EqualsAndHashCode.

Default constructor is without parameters, and lombok @Data have parameters.
You need to add @NoArgsConstructor.

```
    @Data
    @NoArgsConstructor
    private static class Example {
        @JsonProperty(access = JsonProperty.Access.READ_ONLY)
        private String value;
    }

    @Data
    @NoArgsConstructor
    private abstract static class ExampleMixin {
        @JsonProperty(access = JsonProperty.Access.READ_WRITE)
        private String value;
    }
```

Comment: `@RequiredArgsConstructor` only adds final fields to the constructor.  Since `value` is not final, the generated constructor _is_ a no-argument constructor.  The reason your solution works has nothing to do with this and works even when `@NoArgsConstructor` is removed.  The reason it works is the generated getter in the mixin due to `@Data`.