# Jackson Json Processing in scala using Java POJO

Tags: java, json, scala, jackson

I have a use case where my JSON POJO is in java and i need to serialise it in Scala Codebase.

Let's say my pojo is -

```
@Data
public class JobConfigTest {

    private String name;

}
```

and my json processer is -

```
public class jsonmapper {

    private static jsonmapper instance;
    private final ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();

    private jsonmapper() {
        mapper.registerModule(new Jdk8Module());
        mapper.activateDefaultTyping(ptv, ObjectMapper.DefaultTyping.JAVA_LANG_OBJECT);
    }
    public static jsonmapper getInstance() {
        if (instance == null) {
            instance = new jsonmapper();
        }
        return instance;
    }


    public <T> T fromJson(String config, Class<T> clazz) throws JsonProcessingException {
        T lib = null;
        try {
            lib = mapper.readValue(config, clazz);
        } catch (JsonProcessingException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            throw e;
        }
        return lib;
    }
```

When I run the below code in scala Test case it fails -

```
val str : String = "{\"name\": \"Hotel\"}";
jsonmapper.getInstance().fromJson(str, classOf[JobConfigTest])
```

The error i get is -

```
com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.exc.UnrecognizedPropertyException: Unrecognized field "name" (class com.codbase.datavalidation.config.JobConfigTest), not marked as ignorable (0 known properties: ])
 at [Source: (String)"{"name": "Hotel"}"; line: 1, column: 11] (through reference chain: com.codebase.datavalidation.config.JobConfigTest["name"])
```

Comment: What is `@Data`, a Lombok annotation maybe?

Comment: I don't think it's related to Scala though, all your code is Java. Maybe related to https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66597368/why-do-my-field-based-jackson-mixins-break-when-using-lombok-data